# What is actually happening from a semantic perspective with connect?

Tags: react-redux

With a redux connected component, at the bottom of the jsx file before exporting it is connected to the store. It looks like this...

```
const Button = connect(mapStateToProps)(UnconnectedButton);

export default Button;
```

With the second argument being the component you want to connect.

This just looks strange to me. How is the component being invoked by the connect function? I would have expected the innermost parenthesis to just be a comma separating the arguments. What's actually going on here and is this legitimate javaScript syntax that can be used even without the react-redux library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now that this is an example of currying. This is when a function is composed to take multiple arguments one at a time. The first function call returns another function, so the second set of parentheses then invokes that function and passes in the new argument. [Read more about currying here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983).